# running GTrendR yields a 'Not enough search volume' error

Tags: r

I'm running the following code on R 3.0.1 (WIN 64 bits). GTrendsR version is 1.2.1. 
This package is intended to access the GOOGLE Trends from R to download google searches frequencies.

```
# First time execution
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools") 
install_bitbucket("GTrendsR", "persican")



# NORMAL execution

library("GTrendsR")
usr = "googleusername "
psw = "password "
ch  <- gconnect(usr, psw,verbose=TRUE)
trends <- gtrends(ch, query = "facebook",geo = "CA", cat="0")
```

Bu after the last line execution , the only thing I get is

```
Error: Not enough search volume. Please change your search terms.
```

This example is supposed to retrieve the frequencies of "facebook" google searches in Canada, so it's impoosible not having enough search volume for the 'facebook' keyword. Your advice is highly appreciated

Comment: Don't you think that error message might be telling you to narrow the search?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried with several keywords, and always get the same result. This is probably some kind of bug related to my own configuration.

Comment: Check Google Trends in a browser, IMHO you have reached the quota limit, or there was some problem with the authentication.

Comment: After several weeks of googling I found a common issue with python and the way R handles cookies depending on computer/software specific configurations. There seems to be no easy answer to this so I'm using the more primitive but efective GTrends package.

Comment: Packages like this should be removed from CRAN if they're clearly broken

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue related to two-step authentication; see [this thread](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/31) on GitHub for the details. The solution recommended by the package's creators is to set up a second Google account without two-step authentication that you only use for these types of activities. Perhaps future versions of the package will render that recommendation moot.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as user3542643 but after playing around with various packages and such I cannot reliably reproduce it on *all* queries. In fact, right now I cannot reproduce it at all but am having problems with another error message.

This first query works *most* of the time:

```
library(gtrendsR)
usr <- "xxxx"
psw <- "myPsw"
gconnect(usr, psw)
lang_trend <- gtrends(c("data is", "data are"), res="week")
```

However, this next query works *some* of the time and when it doesn't work, it produces the error message that follows:

```
lang_trend <- gtrends(c("statistical learning", "implicit learning"), res="week")

Warning message:
In names(trend)[3:ncol(trend)] <- unlist(strsplit(queryparams[1],  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

About ½ the time even this second query works well. I am very confused by the probabilistic outcomes.

BTW: I no longer use Google's two-step authentication -- so whatever problems it may cause, surely are not causing the ones I have found.

Answer (score 0):

getting the following error message

```
Error: Not enough search volume. Please change your search terms.
```

There is, say, a 90% probability that it means you actually **reached some quota limitation**. Google trends has progressively set up quite stringent limitations on the volume of data/the number of queries you can make on a given day an on the rate per second. Several forum discussions mention that ([here](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/108) for instance)

What I've witnessed is

- some people mention the limit of 200 queries/day
- if the rate is too fast error can occur after a random number of queries
- setting up a random `sys.sleep()` didn't completely solve the issue
- switching accounts to change the session doesn't work
- If you try too hard you'll get a 24h ban on your IP.

The only solution i can think of would be to set up a Macro in your browser to get "semi-manually" the data, up to now google didn't set any limitations on the number of manual requests. Though, I guess they could even detect that, they're good!